# Is there any other way to deploy desktop app ( WPF or WinForm ) from Web other than ClickOnce

Tags: deployment

Is there any other way to deploy desktop app ( WPF or WinForm ) from WebServer(Exampe http://mydownload.com) other than ClickOnce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply share a .zip file, and have the end user unzip it - or you can use Squirrel: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows